# Is there a way to load data from a text file on the same server as the web page?

Tags: javascript

Recently I have started working on a simple top down tile based program where you can move a player character around the map and zoom in and out of the map.

It's been going well, I have a background drawn and now I want to start drawing some tiles.

Currently I have something that looks kind of like this:

```
var tileset1 = new Image();
tileset1.src = "Images/Tileset1.gif";
var tx = [];
var ty = [];
var txo = [];
var tyo = []; //Background tile x and y on the map and the x and y offset in the image for drawing
var tilesize = 32; //constant for each tiles width and height in pixels.

function map1data() {
    "use strict";
    tx[0] = 0;
    ty[0] = 0;
    txo[0] = 0;
    tyo[0] = 0;
    tx[1] = 32;
    ty[1] = 0;
    txo[1] = 32;
    tyo[1] = 0;
}
map1data();
ctx.drawImage(tileset1, txo[i], tyo[i], tilesize, tilesize, tx[i], ty[i], tilesize, tilesize);
```

This works fine, but my main issue is with using arrays to draw the tiles and having to give the properties of each tile by hard coding it into the script.

If my map had 100 tiles in it, i would have to manually write 400 lines of code, not ideal.

So what I'm wondering is there a way to source a plain text file on the actual server the web page is hosted on (As in, in the same root file system as the index page?) and set a variable to the contents of that, like I did with the images? Rather than having to use DOM to request it from a specific servers url?

Comment: Yes, That is the basic idea of Ajax. Fetch the document and process the file and store it into the variable.

Comment: I don't think the poster wants to make an ajax request. They say "Rather than having to use DOM to request it from a specific servers url"

Comment: If you don't want to use ajax you can just have another javascript file on your server and in that file assign your data to a global variable. Then include that js file in a script tag. When the page loads the script will run and assign the data to the var.

Comment: You can either do this client-side with ajax, as epascarello pointed out, or server-side with some kind of server-side templating or scripting technology, such as NodeJS (JavaScript), PHP (PHP), ASP.Net (various languages), or any of a few dozen others.

Comment: Also note that the DOM has nothing to do with ajax. The DOM is the model of the document in memory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is there a reason you are not wanting to use ajax? You can use PHP as follows (assume the following file is called myscript.php):

```
//place any opening javascript code here if necessary.
<?php
     // open a file using the fopen function
     // read each line of the file using the fgets function
     // convert each line into your appropriate javascript code such as an array etc.
     // echo the javascript code
//place any closing javascript code here if necessary.
```

Then you can include it just like including any other javascript file:

```
<script src="myscript.php"></script>
```

Also, since it is in a PHP script, you can reference files whether they are in the web root or outside of the web root.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest) API. What this does is tell the browser to request the specified file from the server without loading a new page and presenting it to the user. You can then assign the returned data to a variable in your code and work with it from there.

If you don't mind using jQuery, you could use the `.get()` [method](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/), which has simpler syntax:

```
$.get( "tiles.txt", function( data ) {
  // assign 'data' to an existing variable or pass into a function
});
```

You might want to look into storing the data as JSON or another similar format rather than plaintext (it'll be easier to manipulate).